# Получение данных с помощи curl php

Tags: php, api, curl

Нужно взять данные передаваемые через curl на страницу.
У меня это почему то не получается, я делаю что то не так.

Вот код curl

```
class testApi {
        private $_tokenApi;
        private $_url;
        
        function __construct($api){
            $this->_tokenApi = $api;
            $this->_url = "https://***.ru/api/";
        }
    
        private function sendRequest($method, array $content = [], $post = false){
            $ch = curl_init();
    
            if($post){
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_url . $method);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($content));
            }else{
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_url . $method . '/?' . http_build_query($content));
            }
    
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                'Accept: application/json',
                'Content-Type: application/json',
            ]); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return json_decode($result, 1);
        }
    
        public function getSallesList($ruw){
            $params = [
                "token" => "fd",
                "ruw" => $ruw
            ];
            return $this->sendRequest("salesAllList", $params, 1);
        }
    }
```

`sendRequest` - принимает название страницы $method (у меня salesAllList - ниже покажу код этой страницы), `$content` - параметры в формате json, `$post` - ну тут понятно, post, или get. Метод не мой, взял его с интернета, но вроде все мне понятно. Использовал я его для API других сервисов, теперь хочу сделать у себя тоже api, только для меня что бы не было ни кому доступа кроме меня.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($content));` - создаю массив $content, перевожу его в json.

Вот код метода `salesAllList` - это куда отправляю параметры $content

```
public function salesAllList(){      
  print_r(json_encode($_POST));
}
```

Ни чего нет! Но обратный вывод есть.
Вот тут я его вызываю:

```
public function index(){
        $salles = $this->testApi->getSallesList(1);
        print_r($salles);
}
```

Вывод вот такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помогите мне, что я делаю не так?

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:**
`curl_getinfo()` - содержит: `Array ( [url] => https://***.ru/api/salesAllList [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8 [http_code] => 200 [header_size] => 156 [request_size] => 132 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 1.140317 [namelookup_time] => 0.00657 [connect_time] => 0.006849 [pretransfer_time] => 0.036521 [size_upload] => 22 [size_download] => 2 [speed_download] => 1 [speed_upload] => 19 [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => 22 [starttransfer_time] => 0.036631 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => 37.**.192.** [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 443 [local_ip] => 37.**.192.** [local_port] => 34828 [http_version] => 3 [protocol] => 2 [ssl_verifyresult] => 0 [scheme] => HTTPS [appconnect_time_us] => 35937 [connect_time_us] => 6849 [namelookup_time_us] => 6570 [pretransfer_time_us] => 36521 [redirect_time_us] => 0 [starttransfer_time_us] => 36631 [total_time_us] => 1140317 ) Array ( )`

Comment: `print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')))`.

Comment: @teran спасибо за быстрый ответ. 
Я попробовал это написать в `salesAllList`, и ни чего не выводиться. Можете уточнить если я делаю не правильно?

Comment: `curl_getinfo` что выдаёт?

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($content));` замените на `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);`

Comment: @ArchDemon спасибо что ответили!
Сделал как вы и сообщили мне. Ни чего не изменилось. Очень странно, я как понимаю должно все работать но не работает. Почему тогда я к другим сервисам api могу подключаться а у себя нет? Может я просто как то принимаю данные не так?

Comment: @ArchDemon 
В `curl_getinfo` -> меняется `size_upload`  если изменять "token",  ` [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8`.
К сожалению я не могу все показать вам, потому что текст слишком большой.

Comment: вы не показали результат `curl_getinfo` (добавьте к вопросу, а не в комментарий).  `print_r(json_encode($_POST));` заменить на `echo json_encode($_POST);`. Перед `return json_decode($result, 1);` закиньте `var_dump($result);`

Comment: @ArchDemon добавил в вопросе `curl_getinfo`.
Сделал все как вы сказали, результат вот такой:

`var_dump` - показывает `string(2) "[]"`;
А `print_r($salles)` (это в index где я и вызываю getSallesList) - показывает `Array ( )`